# C++ GetAsyncKeyState not working in Console Window

Tags: c++, winapi

I'm trying to learn and experiment abit with C++ this is how it looks so far:

```
int main() {
    std::vector<std::string> lines = {
        "Fancy Centered Text!",
    };

    if (GetAsyncKeyState(VK_F1) & 1)
    {
        cout << "LOL";
        if (GetAsyncKeyState(VK_SPACE))
        {
            Sleep(100);
            keybd_event(0x50, 0, 0, 0);
            Sleep(100);
            keybd_event(0x50, 0, KEYEVENTF_KEYUP, 0);
        }
    }

    int num_cols = 75;

    // VIRTUAL BORDER
    std::cout << std::endl;
    for (int i = 0; i < num_cols; ++i) std::cout << ' ';
    std::cout << ' ' << std::endl;

    // OUTPUT
    for (int i = 0; i < lines.size(); ++i) {
        centerify_output(lines[i], num_cols);
        std::cout << std::endl;
    }

    // VIRTUAL BORDER
    std::cout << std::endl;
    for (int i = 0; i < num_cols; ++i) std::cout << ' ';
    std::cout << ' ' << std::endl;
}
```

So the problem is when the user presses F1 and left clicks it will press down a key once (in this case Q as example).
It compiles without error or problem and when i try to press F1 and left click nothing really happens.

Maybe im just too blind to see whats wrong, any help would be great!

Comment: What are you actually trying to do? What do you hope to achieve by calling `GetAsyncKeyState`? Why do you test the return value in that odd manner? You test in two different ways, both look wrong.

Comment: When i press F1 i want it to print out: "LOL" and if i would press space after i have pressed F1 it should press the Q button on my keyboard. Do you understand what i mean?

Comment: Why did you choose to use `GetAsyncKeyState`? That is not what you need.

Comment: Is there a better way to do this than using GetAsyncKeyState?

Comment: In a console application, I'd expect that you would use a blocking wait for input. I would also expect that you would not resort to the platform API and would use the C++ standard library.

Answer (score 1):

You need to run the GetAsyncKeyState within a loop along with all the functions if you want to register multiple keypresses during the execution and process them.  Otherwise, the program merely finishes execution after recieving a keypress,  you need a loop to jump back to the keypress and receive/process it once more.

Comment: Could you show me a example, im a bit uncertain on how you mean. :/

Comment: Im on my phone atm but basically before your first if () you would put while (1){ and close that after endl; in virtual border. Also move int num cols =75 out of the loop once you do that ( before while). If your still unsure I can write it out in a few mins when I arrive home.

Comment: You mean like this?:            while (true)
 {
  if (GetAsyncKeyState(VK_F1) & 1)
   cout << "LOL";

Comment: Yeah and end that before you end main.  Also incase you havent noticed, the way you structured your if statements makes it so that you must press f1 AND space to execute the stuff in the GetAsyncKeyState(VK_SPACE) if.  Just notifying you.

Comment: The code is also checking the return value of `GetAsyncKeyState(VK_SPACE)` incorrectly.